# Proving that a proposition is a theorem in $L_I$.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

In "Introduction to Mathmatical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson, I was able to prove exercise 1.60 (a) and 1.60(b), but failed to prove 1.60 (c) .It is as follows:

> For any m , the wf
> $(A_1 \leftrightarrow A_2) \lor...\lor (A_1 \leftrightarrow A_m) \lor (A_2 \leftrightarrow A_3) \lor ...(A_2 \leftrightarrow A_m)\lor...\lor (A_{m-1} \leftrightarrow A_m)$  is not a theorem of $L_I$

I first tried to write it as a summation:
$\bigcup _{j=1}^{m-1} \bigcup _{i=2}^m (A_j \leftrightarrow A_i)$

Then I thought of using induction on this summation. 
(i) prove it for $m=2$ 
(ii) Assume that it is proven for $m=k$ 
(iii) Prove it for $m = (k+1)$

But still , the problem didn't got anywhere from there. Can someone give me a different idea?

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

$\text {L}_{\text I}$ is [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) and $\text {IL}$ has the so-called [Disjunction property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties#Disjunction_property):

> The disjunction property is satisfied by a theory if, whenever a sentence $A ∨ B$ is a theorem, then either $A$ is a theorem, or $B$ is a theorem.

The $A_i$s are sentential letters, and thus none of the disjuncts $(A_i \leftrightarrow A_j)$ is a theorem, when $i \ne i$.

Use this fact in a proof by induction on the complexity (number of disjunction signs) of the formula.

---

Compare with Classical Logic: $(A_1 \leftrightarrow A_2)$ is not a tautology, but  $(A_1 \leftrightarrow A_2) \lor (A_1 \leftrightarrow A_3) \lor (A_2 \leftrightarrow A_3)$ is.

Comment: Is there a way to show that IL lacks the disjunctive property?

Comment: @Prithubiswas - my bad... "has the disjunction property".

Comment: See [Propositional Intuitionistic Logic](http://www.mi-ras.ru/~sk/lehre/penn2017/lecture1.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Use part (a). You need to come up with truth-values for $A_1,..., A_m$ that would make your formula take a non-zero truth-value in the many-valued logic described in (a).

I am not sure, but maybe you are misinterpreting the dots in

$$(A_1\leftrightarrow A_2)\vee...\vee(A_1\leftrightarrow A_m)\vee(A_2\leftrightarrow A_3)\vee...\vee(A_2\leftrightarrow A_m)\vee...\vee(A_{m-1}\leftrightarrow A_m).$$

I guess it is meant to be the disjunction of $(A_i\leftrightarrow A_j)$, where $1\leq i < j\leq m$. However, it shouldn't really make any difference.